# Chi-squared distribution: Do I lack information?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-distribution

The text of a problem from my book is:

> The area of houses $(x)$ expressed as $m^2,$ hence $y=x/10,$ follows Chisq(9).
> what's the percentage of houses below $30\,m^2?$

Don't I lack a location/dispersion parameters to this exercise? Is this information sufficient?

Comment: You know the distribution of $Y$, and the scale parameter of $10$ gives the distribution of $X$.  The bottom end of the distribution seems to be $0$, which makes sense as it is an area

Comment: @Henry so you mean 30 is my CV and I need P(Χ2 < 30) = 0.9996, right?

Comment: You want $P(X \le 30)$, which since $y=x/10$ is $P(Y \le 3)$.  That should be a small percentage for a chi-squared distribution with $9$ degrees of freedom

Answer (score 1):

For a chi-squared distribution, you need only the degrees of freedom parameter $\nu = 9,$ which has been provided. Following @Henry's Comment (where the notation has been decoded) you want to evaluate $P(Y < 3)$ for $Y\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=9):$

Depending on the format of your printed chi-squared table, you may be able
to come close to the answer.  We can guess the probability must be small because
$\mathsf{Chisq}(9)$ has mean $9$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{18}.$

In the table I have at hand I can bracket the probability as between 0.025 and 0.050. That is, the probability below 2.7 is about  0.025 and the probability below 3.325 is about 0.05. [Computations in R, where `qchisq` is a chi-squared inverse CDF (quantile function).]

```
qchisq(.025, 9)  # prob .025 in margin of printed table
[1] 2.700389     # corresp. chi-sq value in body of table.
qchisq(.05, 9)
[1] 3.325113
```

Using a statistical calculator or computer software you can get an exact answer. In R, where `pchisq` is a chi-squared CDF we get
$P(Y < 3) = 0.0357.$

```
pchisq(3, 9) 
[1] 0.03570503
```

Relevant plots of the CDF and Density functions of $\mathsf{Chisq}(9)$ are shown below. This distribution has a heavy right tail. Red broken lines illustrate the answer above. (Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) on chi-squared distributions.)

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 curve(pchisq(x,9), 0, 30, lwd=1, ylab="CDF", main="CDF of CHISQ(9)")
  abline(h=0:1, col="green2"); abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(h=c(.025, 0.05), lty="dotted")
  abline(v=c(2.7, 3.325), lty="dotted")
  abline(h=.0357, col="red", lty="dashed")
  abline(v = 3, col="red", lty="dashed")
 curve(dchisq(x,9), 0, 30, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="Density of CHISQ(9)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=3, col="red", lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```